# add Date control to devexpress silverlight grid

Tags: c#, devexpress

Need to add a date picker to a devexpress Silverlight grid so that the first column of the grid is a datepicker.

Inside the xaml can I drag a date picker and drop it or can I set the gridcolum.editsettings property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please assign the [GridColumn.EditSettings](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#Silverlight/DevExpressXpfGridColumnBase_EditSettingstopic) property as follows:

```
<dxg:GridColumn x:Name="colDate" FieldName="Date"> 
    <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings> 
        <dxe:DateEditSettings MaskType="DateTime" Mask="dd-MMM-yyyy" MaskUseAsDisplayFormat="True"/> 
    </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings> 
</dxg:GridColumn>
```

Also you can use the GridControl's design-time capabilities: to specify the type of a column's editor and customize its settings, select the column and choose the type of the required editor via the [Quick Customization Panel](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#Silverlight/CustomDocument5580).